# CSS4では、 Lab 色・LCH 色・ CMYK 色が指定可能になるのでしょうか？

Tags: css

**CSS4では、 Lab 色 ・LCH 色 ・CMYK 色 が指定可能になるのでしょうか？**
・現在検討中の段階？
・それとも決定事項だけれども実際に使用できるようになるのはずっと先の話？

---

[CSS Color Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-4/)
・8 Device-independent Colors: Lab and LCH
・12 Device-dependent CMYK Colors: the device-cmyk() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのページの冒頭部分や画面左端に Editor's Draft と書かれているかと思いますが、これは一般論としてW3C標準の策定プロセス上ごく初期の段階のものです。

> Working Groups and Interest Groups may make available "Editor's drafts". Editor's drafts have no official standing whatsoever, and do not necessarily imply consensus of a Working Group or Interest Group, nor are their contents endorsed in any way by W3C.
>   <sub>--- https://www.w3.org/2015/Process-20150901/#maturity-levels</sub>

仮に一部ブラウザで使えたとしても、今後仕様が変わる可能性が十分に考えられますし、場合によっては廃止になる可能性すらあります。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/nakamura001/20120201/1328105899#c1328417061